# run .exe file and parsing of its output.txt file

Tags: vb.net

I want to call an .exe file in my code (vb.net), then i have to execute it. After execution i want to call my output file in that same code to parse the file and collect the data for plotting the graphs.
I have done only first part and I could not be able to call an output file . as I have to manually call it .

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("C:\rs40dk\RunRelap.exe")
    End Sub
End Class
```

its output is .txt file. I am thinking to apply check first if `Process.Start` = ok then proceeds further pick the file but I couldn't be able to put a generic name

Comment: Are you trying to get the output of the RunRelap.exe?

Comment: yes , i want to get its output in vb to plot its graphs

Comment: After running `Process.start(....)`, where is output.txt saved?

Comment: In the same folder but with different names ... that's is the main problem. C:\rs40dk\Simple_Pipe...... this simple_pipe contains  output file with different names with extension ".o"

Answer (score 0):

While the process is running
Do nothing
End while

Now pull data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

I believe that link should have the method to do the status. I'm in a car or I'd find the correct line instead of a Pseudocode while loop.

Comment: I would recommend against doing a busy-wait.  There is a perfectly cromulent way to do this that doesn't involve spinning your own process at 100% CPU utilization: Call `WaitForExit` on the `Process` object returned from `Process.Start`.  There may be some additional considerations, I note that there are remarks on `Process.StandardError` that suggest you may need to read the process `StandardError` stream to avoid deadlocking in `WaitForExit`.

Comment: That's good but i re-map the whole scenario and reached at some algorithm in which i found if following steps........... 1) input file 2) configuration file 3) my code will then process it 4) depicts all results ......... i read about configuration files as they are helpful in converting some .exe results as our requirement ... now i need your suggestion is it more good than previous one ?

Comment: I just did the simplest method that came to mind. The configuration file is probably best for your uses. Craig's comments are totally valid, as well. Unless it takes too long, use any valid method. You do have to ensure that there is a file output because you may not and need to avoid falling into a trap.